# What is the easiest way to swap any 2 tokens on Uniswap?

Tags: erc-20, uniswap, swaps

I would like to swap any 2 tokens, which could either have a UniswapV2 pool, UniswapV3 pool or that do not have a pool in common.

From my understanding, I would need to find a route from token1 to token2 somehow and perform single or multiple hop trade. Basically, I would like to do what Uniswap does, but in a simplified version.